# Speed increase in a ventrui relative to its initial speed

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Does the air speed through a ventrui reach a higher final speed if its speed prior to entering the ventrui is higher than if it entered the same ventrui with a lower speed?

I should add that the volume is the same in both cases.

Comment: ventrui -> venturi

Answer (score 0):

Since $Q = v_1A_1 = v_2A_2$, if $v_1$ is greater, then $v_2$ will also be greater ($A_1$ and $A_2$ are the same because you're using the same Venturi tube).